# Верно ли расставлены запятые в этом предложении?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение

Лучше уж так, чем копать яму неизвестно чем, а главное, тела можно завалить ветками сверху как лежат, без того, чтобы перетаскивать их или трогать.

Answer (score 2):

Можно предложить такой вариант:

*Лучше уж так, чем копать яму неизвестно чем, **а главное ― тела можно завалить ветками сверху, как лежат, без того чтобы перетаскивать их или трогать.***

**Пояснение**

1. **Тире** при обособлении вводного слова "а главное" усиливает его выделение, а также делит распространенное предложение на две тематические части.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122 Пункт 9(11)
11) Слово главное в значении ‘особенно важно; особенно существенно’ является вводным и выделяется запятыми: Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное, чтобы было интересно; Детали можно опустить, а главное — чтобы было занимательно — запятую после союза а поставить нельзя, и для усиления выделения после вводного сочетания поставлено тире;

2. ***...завалить ветками сверху, как (они)лежат, без того чтобы перетаскивать их или трогать.***  Здесь к сказуемому "можно завалить" относится **ряд обстоятельств**, выраженных различным образом: наречие, неполное сравнительное придаточное и изъяснительное (местоименное) придаточное с составным союзом "без того чтобы".

Пример такого союзного сочетания: ...создавая условия самого зрения, даже **без того чтобы** они обязательно были исторически реализованы. [И. М. Чубаров. Коллективная чувственность: теории и практики левого авангарда (2014)]

Answer (score 0):

Ну мне кажется что помимо этого, есть только один вариант как расставить запятые по другому. Это если пере "как" ставится запятая. Ведь перед "чтобы" и "а" запятая ставится почти всегда. Вот что я смог откопать по поводу "как":

Запятая перед союзом КАК ставится в трех случаях:

1. Если этот союз входит в обороты, близкие по роли в предложении к вводным словам, например: КАК ПРАВИЛО, КАК ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ, КАК СЛЕДСТВИЕ, КАК ВСЕГДА, КАК СЕЙЧАС, КАК НАРОЧНО, КАК НАПРИМЕР, КАК ТЕПЕРЬ: Утром, как нарочно, начался дождь;
2. Если этот союз соединяет части сложноподчиненного предложения, например: Мы долго смотрели, как тлеют угли костра;
3. Если в предложении есть обстоятельство, выраженное сравнительным оборотом, который начинается с союза КАК, например: Ее голос звенел, как самый маленький колокольчик;

Если предложение продолжается после оборотов с союзом КАК, то необходимо поставить еще одну запятую в конце оборота. Например: Внизу, как зеркало, блестела вода; Мы долго смотрели, как тлеют угли костра, не в силах оторваться от этого зрелища.

Не обособляются обороты с союзом КАК в пяти случаях:

1. Если оборот с союзом КАК в предложении выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия, например: Тропинка извивалась как змея. В таких случаях оборот с КАК можно заменить наречием (ПО-ЗМЕИНОМУ) или существительным в творительном падеже (ЗМЕЕЙ). К сожалению, не всегда обстоятельства образа действия можно с полной уверенностью отличить от обстоятельств сравнения.
2. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав фразеологизма, например: Во время обеда она сидела как на иголках;
3. Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: Она держится как хозяйка;
4. Если союз КАК стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым (без этого союза там требовалось бы поставить тире), например: Озеро как зеркало;
5. Если сравнительному обороту предшествует отрицание НЕ или частицы СОВСЕМ, СОВЕРШЕННО, ПОЧТИ, ВРОДЕ, ТОЧЬ-В-ТОЧЬ, ИМЕННО, ПРОСТО, например: Они все делают не как соседи или Волосы у нее вьются точь-в-точь как у матери;

Кроме этого, надо помнить, что слово КАК может быть частью составного союза КАК… ТАК И… или ТАК КАК, а также оборотов С ТЕХ ПОР КАК, С ТОГО ВРЕМЕНИ КАК, ПО МЕРЕ ТОГО КАК, КАК МОЖНО МЕНЬШЕ (БОЛЬШЕ) и др. В этом случае, естественно, запятая перед КАК тоже не ставится.

Если верить этой информации то запятая перед "как" ставиться не должна, и у вас всё правильно.

Поправьте если я где-то ошибаюсь.